# Instantiating object of type parameter with a parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have got a template class as follows:

```java
class MyClass<T>
{
    T field;
    public void myMethod()
    {
       field = new T(true); // gives compiler error
    }
}
```

How do I create a new instance of T in my class?

Comment: You cannot call a supplier with a parameter, now please reopen this ticket so others may offer their response including working code.

Comment: Your comments are not making sense. @erickson provided a perfectly good way to do this in the other question `MyClass<StringBuilder> it = new MyClass<>(StringBuilder::new);`, but its non-trivial for `new MyClass2<>(() -> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"));` now please allow answers!